# What is wrong with this program? why is it not quitting the loop?

Tags: c++

So i am trying to make a program that will determine if the number is happy number or not. But the program doesn't seems to quit the loop and nothing happens after the number is put in.

Is there something that I am missing or do I do the program wrong? (Only learned for loop, while loop, do while loop, and also if statement and can only use them.)

I have been doing this program for 3 days but still can't figure out what is wrong with this program. It will be nice if you can teach me where it goes wrong. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int number, temp, count;
cout<<"please enter a number :";
cin>>number; // to ask for input

while(number != 1 and number != 4)
{
    while(number !=0)
    {
        number = number/10;
        count += 1;  //start to calculate how many digits are in the number
    }
    while(count!=0)
    {
        number == number + (temp/(10^(count-1))^2); // to add the square of the number
        temp = temp%(10^(count-1));
        count-=1;
    }
    if(count == 0)
    {
        temp = number; // to set temp as number after the program is over so it can run again if it is not done
    }
}

if(number == 1){
    cout<<"This is a happy number"; // to print result
}
else if(number == 4){
    cout<<"This is not a happy number"; // to print result
}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ^ is not exponent in C++, it's exclusive OR.

Comment: and `and` is not the same as `&&`

Comment: If I can see the flow chart because I can't understand what is the program supposed to do. Your question is  getting down voted. Besides, the while loop will never exit until it meets the condition, such as `number` is equal to 0.

Comment: count and temp need to be initialized. The compiler should have issued a warning about using uninitialized variables.

Comment: Just about every development environment has [a debugging program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that you can use to control the execution of your program, stopping every line if need be, so that you can examine the state of the program (the variables) before continuing. The debugger is probably the best productivity tool you will ever find. It can turn 3 days of searching and a post to SO into a few minutes of stepping and a groan of mental anguish.

Comment: It will be many error if you run your code and there are  also `not C++ language` there.

Comment: Go here: [http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson3.html] [1] Learn simple example. Understand each characteristic of the loops.

Comment: Also pay heed to the compiler warnings. They are often telling you that you have code that is doing something grammatically correct but logically questionable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all properly initialise the varibles,
count is taking some arbitrary values and then calcuting the number of digits with such garbage values will give you a wrong answer and also the value of temp varible is not initialised which is also taking garbage values 
and use pow(x,y) function in cpp under  library for calculating power of a number, x^y will not calculate power in cpp

and you can use gdb to debug your code futher if you encounter any errors

Comment: Actually be careful with that `pow` function. It operates in floating point and may result in an approximate value that will be truncated to the wrong number when converted back to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

As a few others have pointed out in the comments, the logic of program is ambiguous, for the simple program as you've described I don't think you need the inside while loops. A review of some basic looping concepts may help as LoveTronic has noted. However, to help you play around with a working program I modified your program to do what you've described in the question.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int number;

   cout << "please enter a number :";
   cin >> number; // to ask for input

   while (true) {
      if ( number == 1 ) {
         cout << "This is a happy number\n";
         return 1;
      }
      else if ( number == 4 ) {
         cout << "this is not a happy number\n";
         return 1;
      }
      cout << "please enter a number :";
      cin >> number; // to ask for input
   }
   return 0; // this will never reach
}
```